# What is the OHLC of a candle when there are no trades

Tags: technical-analysis

I hope I'm asking this in the right place. Couldn't find any definitive info anywhere.

When creating a candle / time series / bucket, is the open of the series the first price in that series and not the close of the previous series?

If so, what is the OHLC of a series if there are no trades in that series? Are they all set to the close of the previous series? Can anyone provide a link to some documentation on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly, it there are no trades in a time period it will be just the last traded price, so you will just get a dash as such "-" representing that the open, close, high and low are just the same as the last traded price.

You will find this a lot on intraday charts of less liquid stocks. Sometimes there might be only one trade or a few trades at the same price in the time period, so you get a dash "-" at a slightly different price than the last traded price.

Comment: Thanks. Would love to have found a formal ruleset somewhere.

Comment: Try this site to learn more http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:chart_analysis:introduction_to_candlesticks, but don't know if it will have anything on the question you asked.

Comment: This is another site by Steve Nison https://candlecharts.com/candlestick-training/candles-101/, an expert on Candle Charting in the USA.